# CodeIgniter keeps inserting 2147483647 for int values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Each time i try storing the id 1008218499200959 or any other 'long' int value to the database it's stored as 2147483647 and i have the data length set to 20 so the length shouldn't have been the problem i guess.

Is this a CodeIgniter or database issue?

I later fixed it by changing the data type to varchar but i'll still like to know why it behaves that way. Thank you.

### -- Table structure for table `applicants`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applicants` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with MySQL based on the id type you have defined.  The largest int value is 2147483647.  Check out their docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

**Other options:**

- Signed BIGINT can get you to 9223372036854775807
- Unsigned BIGINT can get you to 18446744073709551615
- The maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65

(see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html for more details).

Answer (score 1):

It is a database issue.  That is the largest integer, and you are trying to put in a larger value.  You should define the value to be `decimal(20)` rather than `int(20)`.

Note:  Codeigniter could have its own issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we create DB  we never give value to `int`. `INT` use `4Bytes` of storage to store value, as well as it Use [maximum value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) as 2147483647.

You can choose two option

1. Remove length from `int`. (Just Place `int`)
2. Or Use `decimal`. So you can define length as well (`decimal(20)`)